# Repl.it Install Keyboard

Tags: python, replit

I'm trying to write a code that displays a text when a particular key is pressed.
If anyone can help me figure out how to install keyboard in repl.it, please let me know.
This is a code for a maze, which moves the characters through it using arrow keys. Useless piece of information, but perhaps background detail would be important.

I wanted the text to be displayed when I pressed an arrow key, so I could develop that into my maze.
I tried installing keyboard, but import keyboard doesn't work. Doing pip install keyboard inside the shell doesn't work, nor does sudo pip3 install keyboard, or pip3 install keyboard.
I tried updating my pip install, but now it's giving me this error:

```
error: externally-managed-environment

This environment is externally managed This command has been disabled as it tries to modify the immutable
    `/nix/store` filesystem.

To use Python with Nix and nixpkgs, have a look at the online documentation:
    <https://nixos.org/manual/nixpkgs/stable/#python>.

note: If you believe this is a mistake, please contact your Python installation or OS distribution provider. You can override this, at the risk of breaking your Python installation or OS, by passing --break-system-packages.
```

I've looked it up in the repl.it community, but there's nothing there, so I'm stuck with my assignment.
Importing keyboard gives me the result:

```
pygame 2.5.2 (SDL 2.28.2, Python 3.10.11)
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
Working
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/Maze-Rough-Work/main.py", line 32, in <module>
    if keyboard.is_pressed("a"):
  File "/home/runner/Maze-Rough-Work/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keyboard/__init__.py", line 410, in is_pressed
    _listener.start_if_necessary()
  File "/home/runner/Maze-Rough-Work/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keyboard/_generic.py", line 35, in start_if_necessary
    self.init()
  File "/home/runner/Maze-Rough-Work/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keyboard/__init__.py", line 196, in init
    _os_keyboard.init()
  File "/home/runner/Maze-Rough-Work/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keyboard/_nixkeyboard.py", line 113, in init
    build_device()
  File "/home/runner/Maze-Rough-Work/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keyboard/_nixkeyboard.py", line 109, in build_device
    ensure_root()
  File "/home/runner/Maze-Rough-Work/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keyboard/_nixcommon.py", line 174, in ensure_root
    raise ImportError('You must be root to use this library on linux.')
ImportError: You must be root to use this library on linux.
```

Using pip install pynput is giving me the same error:

```
error: externally-managed-environment

× This environment is externally managed
╰─> This command has been disabled as it tries to modify the immutable
    `/nix/store` filesystem.
    
    To use Python with Nix and nixpkgs, have a look at the online documentation:
    <https://nixos.org/manual/nixpkgs/stable/#python>.

note: If you believe this is a mistake, please contact your Python installation or OS distribution provider. You can override this, at the risk of breaking your Python installation or OS, by passing --break-system-packages.
hint: See PEP 668 for the detailed specification.
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `pynput`, instead of `keyboard`.

Install it like this: `pip install pynput`, and hopefully that should work.

Here's a snippet of code to get you started:

```
from pynput import keyboard

def on_press(key):
    print(key)

with keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

When you run this program, whatever key you press, you should see it pop up in the shell like this: `Key.right`. `Key.right` in this case because I pressed the right arrow key. `Pynput` is a great rounded choice, as it also supports both controlling and listening to the mouse and keyboard. For more information, I suggest you check out the [documentation](https://pypi.org/project/pynput).

It would help if you also explained what your error was with installing `keyboard`, you showed the error with upgrading pip, but you didn't show the error when trying to install `keyboard`, so it would help if you showed that. If `pynput` cannot install as well, then I recommend figuring out what's wrong with your installation and pip before anything else.

Comment: Still not working. It's giving me a crazy error:

Comment: Could you show the error message, so I can give you feedback? Also, please take note of my suggestion to show the error message with pip as well.

Comment: I showed it above. I red edited the question. I have no idea what's up with pip

Comment: I don't think this is just a problem with installing keyboard, I think this is more a problem with pip itself. What version of python do you have?

Comment: I don't really know. I'm just using the repl.it python. If you know anywhere else I can run a python or pygame code, that would be great.

Comment: What operating system do you have? Linux? Windows? MacOS? Ubuntu?

Comment: I use a Windows 10 pro

Comment: Instead of using replit, you can try using IDLE. Go to https://python.org and try installing the latest version of IDLE. That should fix your problem.